# Method for variable substitution in multiple summation

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, sequences-and-series

I want to ask: is there any ***general method*** for variable substitution in multiple summation?

For example in the following equation a new variable $\lambda=n+m-2\mu$ is introduced to transform the LHS to the RHS 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{\mu=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{m+n}{2}\right\rfloor}f(n,m,\mu,n+m-2\mu) = \sum_{\lambda=0}^\infty \sum_{\mu=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{2\mu+\lambda}f(n,2\mu+\lambda-n,\mu,\lambda)$$

Another example, in which a new variable $\delta=m+n+2 p-2 k-2 \mu-2 \sigma$ is introduced

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{p=0}^M \sum _{k=0}^p \sum _{\sigma =0}^{p-k}\quad \sum _{\mu =0}^{\left\lfloor
   \frac{m+n}{2}+p-k-\sigma \right\rfloor } f(n,m,\mu ,p,k,\sigma ,m+n+2 p-2 k-2 \mu-2 \sigma )$$
$$=
\sum _{\delta =0}^{\infty } \sum _{\mu =0}^{\infty } \sum _{p=0}^M \quad\sum _{\beta =0}^{\min \left(p,\left\lfloor \frac{\delta
   }{2}+\mu \right\rfloor \right)}\quad \sum _{n=0}^{2 (\mu -\beta )+\delta }\quad \sum _{k=0}^{p-\beta }\;\; f(n,\delta +2 \mu-2 \beta -n,\mu
   ,p,k,p-\beta -k,\delta ) $$

**Additional remarks:** my goal is using a new summation index, e.g. $\lambda$, to express a particular linear combination of the old indices, which is appointed by me, e.g. $n+m-2\mu$. So this is a linear coordinate transformation. My problem is how to determine all the lower and upper bounds of the new summation indices frame, as well as the summation steps which are possibly not $1$.

I wonder whether there is a systematical and efficient technology, so I may be able to do those transformations automatically by programming.

Comment: Any reference books and articles will be grateful.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what the substitution should achieve. Otherwise, the question is a bit too vague. In your examples, I don't see any great simplification resulting from the substitutions, which is what confuses me.

Comment: @gowers Sorry for confusing, I added some additional explanations, hope it help making my question more clear.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active 

Comment: Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik spend a good part of a chapter talking about notation for multiple sums and their manipulation in the book Concrete Mathematics.  Chapter 2, if memory serves.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.20 

Comment: @Will Jagy: Thanks for suggestion. I've posted it there.
@Gerhard Paseman: Great! I read the Chapt.2 and found the interesting Iverson's convention, which led me to the wikipedia page for "Iverson bracket" and Knuth's note on arxiv (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211).

Comment: link to the same question on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52846/method-for-variable-substitution-in-multiple-summation